# Python program to match string based on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a python program that allows user to enter input
like `Apple,Ball` and it if matches the line in the file print it.
so far I am able to get this.

```
import re
import sys
print('Enter the values')
value1=input()

try:
    filenm1="D:\names.txt"
    t=open(filenm1,'r')
    regexp=re.search(value1,line)
    for line in t:
        if regexp:
            print(line)
catch IOerror:
    print('File not opened')
sys.exit(0)
```

Sample Input File

```
Apple
Ball
Stackoverflow
Call
Doll

User input : App
Output : Apple
```

now I want to modify this program to search by 
user input : `App,Doll`
Output :

```
Apple
Doll
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: For us to help you, you'd have to state precisely: a) What is your question b) What you are tried so far (show a **Minimal Complete Verifiable Example**) c) Where are you getting stuck d) Please indent your code..

Comment: You are calling the variable `line` before you assigned it.

Comment: `'App,Doll'.split(',') = ['App','Doll']`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your loop into this:

```
import sys
print('Enter the values')
value1=input()
value1=value1.split(',')

try:
    filenm1="D:\names.txt"
    t=open(filenm1,'r')
    for line in t:
        alreadyPrinted = False
        for value in value1:
            if value in line:
                if not alreadyPrinted: #this bit prevents line being printed twice
                    print(line)
                    alreadyPrinted = True
except IOerror:
    print('File not opened')
sys.exit(0)
```